# How to Write a Generic Rails CRUD Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two controllers that are essentially the same that I'm trying to consolidate/"DRY" up/refactor/or whatever. I search and find various solutions but can't seem to implement any of them.

Sample code of the two controllers to be consolidated:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update]

  def update
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
      flash[:success] = "Client updated"
      redirect_to @client
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

end
```

~

```
class ItemCatsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update]

  def update
    @item_cat = ItemCat.find(params[:id])
    if @item_cat.update_attributes(params[:item_cat])
      flash[:success] = "Item Category updated"
      redirect_to @item_cat
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

What I suspect I need to do is create a super controller, but I'm getting stuck at finding a generic way to refer to the models.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'd really like to avoid adding any extra gems/plugins to make it work; I'd prefer a "manual"/non-magical solution so that I can understand what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use a gem, take a look at [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources). Beyond this, I would suggest leaving it as-is. I is unlikely that you're going end up with better code by trying to remove this little bit of boilerplate. If you take a gander at that gem's code you will see that quite a lot of magic is involved-- I suspect a home-rolled solution will leave you with both more lines of code and more complex and error-prone code then you currently have.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with that answer, but I can see your point.

Comment: Fair enough. If you're keen to do it anyway, take a look at how inherited_resources [does it](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/blob/master/lib/inherited_resources/class_methods.rb#L291). Specifically, `self.name.sub(/Controller/, '').singularize.constantize` will give you your model based on the controller name, but only in this case. The method I linked to solves it for the general case, but it's rather long.